# Jquery UI accordion Does not properly work dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, accordion

This is the code

hear the Accordion correct format

[image]

Using this code the accordion not work properly

```
    <div>
    <div id="accordion">
    <div th:each="pattern : ${patterns}">       

        <h4><p th:text="${pattern.questionPattern}"/></h4>  
              /*if the pattern the </div> close hear the accordion not work properly */

        <div>
        <table>

            <tr th:each="q : ${questions}"> 


        <div  th:if="${q.questionPattern.id ==pattern.id }">
                            <p> 
                 <input type="checkbox" class="ads_Checkbox"
                th:text="${q.questionName}" id="checkBoxId"
                onclick="validate()"
                th:onclick="'javascript:Select(\'' + ${q.id} + '\',this);'"
                name="checkbox" /><img border="0"
                th:attr="src=@{${q.imagePath}} , 

                            title=#{background}, alt=#{background}"
                style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" /></p>


        </div>  
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

the out put  is not the right format.

how to get the correct format..?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the html page rendered using firebug that. Do it create the H4 and DIV tag properly
Can you provide fiddle for same if possible?

Comment: this values are dynamic and the pattern on the accordion and the questions are inside the accordion.. But the accordion shows the pattern inside the accordion and question as the accordion head
i don'nt know how to create fiddle  alsomeans inside my codes

Comment: I cant say the exact solution util i see the issue live.
Can suggest one more thing to apply accordion after the page is getting rendered also use
$(document).ready(function(){});